# Why are many OnTouchListeners being initialized at once?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have the following line of code:

`convertView.setOnTouchListener(new ListListener(viewHolder, position));`

and the following corresponding block:

```
private class ListListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public SwipeDetector(ViewHolder h, int p) {
            Log.d("ListAdapter", "New ListAdapter listener Created.");
            holder = h;
            position = p;
        }
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("ListAdapter", "new motionEvent.");
        }
}
```

When I touch the screen, I get hundreds of logs saying "New ListAdapter listener Created." Yet, despite the fact that it seems like many are being created, only one seems to be handling the onTouch, as expected. Why are so many listeners being created? Should I therefore keep any intensive logic out of the constructor?

Comment: When the ListView loads, I do get a bunch that seems to be per item. But once the View has loaded, just touching one item causes hundreds more to be created even if the view hasn't moved.

Comment: Thank you, but that answers why different motions are called multiple times, but not why multiple listeners are constructed.